# Removing Wrapped Words

Tags: html, css, button, media-queries, word-wrap

I have two buttons, originally being "Join" and "Create".  Using `@media all and (min-width: 1000px)`, it changes to "Join Room" and "Create Room", respectively.  [Here's what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/Bionicrm/P5DEq/3/).

When I use a funky resolution and zoom in, the words "Join Room" (and the other one) wrap to a new line, increasing the size of the button, which is what I want to avoid:

### [image: Join Room and Create Room show wrapped]

- I don't want to use `white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;` because you'll still be able to see the beginning of the word "Room".
- I want to keep everything on one line at all cost.  I also don't want to just increase the 1000px just so it looks good for people with 800×600 but empty for those with 1920×1080.
- I'm also asking for a pure CSS method.
- I have a bit of OCD if you know what I mean, and I want to make sure that I account for *everyone* of all resolutions and those with an increased/decreased font size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete your media query and add a bit of ccs to `.roombuttons` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/P5DEq/5/

```
.roombuttons {
    -webkit-transition:width .2s;
    background:#FFF;
    border:none;
    border-radius:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
    margin:auto;
    transition:width .2s;
    width:60%;

    overflow: hidden;
    padding:0 25px;
    font-size:3em;
    line-height: 2em;
    height: 2em;

}
```

Since the text's container's height is equal to the line height, and overflow is hidden, it will show the first line of text, and the text that wraps to the next line(s) will be hidden.

Comment: I wanted to have everything go on one line, and because of the block display, "Room" will always be on the next line.  Thanks though!

Comment: ok, I guess I have no idea what you mean by "I want to keep everything on a new line at all costs". Currently, I see either one word buttons, "Join" and "Create", which become two word buttons at a certain width, with both words on one line: "Join Room" and "Create Room" .. what formatting change did you need ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake, I meant to say "on one line".  I just changed it.  Basically I just want "Join Room" and "Create Room" on one line, not wrapping to the other.  I guess what I said meant the opposite :D

Comment: Ah, ok, that's the behavior I see in your current fiddle. Did you want the second word "room" to always show, but shrink the text to fit in the button on small screens ? Just trying to figure out what you want.

Comment: Nah, I wanted the word "Room" (with the word before it) to show on one line, but instead of "Room" wrapping to a new line on a small screen or when zooming in, I want "Room" to disappear (but keep the word before it).

Sorry if you still don't understand XD  Just ask me again if you think it's worth it :D

Comment: Also, you may not be able to see it in the fiddle because I think it depends on your screen resolution and/or text size.

Comment: Got it. I've modified the answer to reflect that. Just set height to line height and hide the overflow